# Magento: Change product name while adding into cart

Tags: magento

I wish to change the product name while adding into shopping cart, So that same product have different name for different users.

Have you any Idea ?

Please help me............

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write observer for that.
The event you will be looking for is `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`, so once this is observed just change the product name.

Inside the observer, you can get the product name with code something like:

```
public function changeProdName($obs) {
    $product = $obs->getProduct();
    $prodNameToChange = $product->getName();
}
```